# uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file via **uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile**. By using instruments I can see that while the file is being uploaded it's size is part of the apps memory. This can cause a memory pressure in case of a big file.

I couldn't find in apple's documents if this is the expected behaviour. Does anyone know if this is the way it's supposed to be or is there a way to change it.

This is the relevant code I believe:

The request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadUrl];
request.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";

[request setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
return request;
```

The task:

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [mForegroundSession uploadTaskWithRequest:theRequest fromFile:fileUrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLSession` can perform an `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:` if you conform to `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and provide a file stream when asked.

Untested, but it would go something like this:

```
// keep a stream available for the delegate
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSInputStream *inputStream;

// // return the request as formed by the OP
- (NSURLRequest *)request {
    // ...
    return request;
}

- (void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    // create the stream
    self.inputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:path];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    // create a task with a "streamedRequest"
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:[self request]];
    [task resume];
}
```

Have the delegate the stream when requested...

```
// NSURLSessionTaskDelegate
//
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task needNewBodyStream:(void (^)(NSInputStream *bodyStream))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(self.inputStream);
}

// optionally track progress
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
    // track progress here
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // check for error and track completion here
}
```

A nice improvement would be to abstract all this into a class with block properties to be invoked for progress and completion, called by the delegate methods.

Comment: thanks for the comment but StreamedRequest doesn't work with background session. Furthermore, I did try it and the memory performance remained the same for some reason.